# Cannot GET /studentLogin

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I am trying to break down code in my main app.js using node.js with express
It was initially working when everything was together in the app.js but after I split them into various modules and I am trying to access the Login page, I get an error which says "**Cannot GET/studentLogin**" which is the login code below. The Login Page is and **ejs** file.

This is the User Login module code:

```
const express = require("express");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
// const student = require(__dirname + '/models/studentModel');

const mongoose = require("mongoose");

// module.exports(student)

let studentSchema = {
  studentID: String,
  password: String,
};

let student = mongoose.model("Student", studentSchema);

const app = express.Router();

// app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

// Getting the Login Page
app.get("/studentLogin", function (req, res, next) {
  res.render("studentLogin.ejs");
});

// Logining the Student in
app.post("/studentLogin", (req, res) => {
  let loginID = req.body.student_ID;
  let loginPassword = req.body.login_password;

  student.findOne({ studentID: loginID }, function (err, student) {
    if (err) {
      console.log(err);
    } else if (student.password != loginPassword) {
      res.redirect("/");
    } else {
      res.render("StudentDashboard");
    }
  });
});

module.exports = app;
```

This is the app.js code below

```
const express = require("express");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const path = require("path");
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

mongoose.connect("mongodb://localhost:27017/Students");

const studentlogin = require(__dirname + "/routes/studentlogin.js");
const app = express();

app.set("views", path.join(__dirname, "views"));
app.set("view engine", "ejs");

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(express.static("public"));

app.get("/", (req, res) => {
  res.render("home");
});

app.use("/studentlogin", studentlogin);

app.listen(3000, () => {
  console.log("Server is up and running");
});
```

Please what am I not doing right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're mounting the router you export from `/routes/studentlogin.js` under `/studentlogin` (`app.use('/studentlogin', studentlogin)`), and you're adding a route into that router with the suffix `/studentLogin` (`app.get('/studentLogin', ...`).

IOW, as it is you would need to navigate to `/studentlogin/studentLogin` to see that view, or just mount the router at the root with

```
app.use(studentlogin);
```

You also don't need to configure the body parser separately in the router module, just do that on the top level instead.

Comment: It worked but it is not able to post the requests from the login page. I get the **Cannot POST /studentLogin.ejs** error

Comment: You're attempting to post to `/studentLogin.ejs` – if you look at how you've mapped your `app.post()`, that's not the path.